# how to substract value present in one row to other row within same table?

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

I'm trying to subtract two rows of different columns. Example table

| C1 | C2 | C3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 2 |  |
| A2 |  | 3 |
| B1 |  | 4 |

So essentially, I want A2-A1 from C3 and C2 columns respectively. My approach was to somehow get values in C2New column and then subtract.

| C1 | C2 | C2New | C3 | C4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 2 | 2 |  |  |
| A2 |  | 2 | 3 | 1 |
| B1 |  |  | 4 |  |

If you are using explorer, here is how you can create the table:

```
let X = datatable( c1:string , c2:int , c3:int )
[  'a1',2,3,
    'a2', 0,3,
    'b1', 0,4
];
X
| project   c1, c2, c3
```

I have tried different joins, selfjoins, lookups and toscalar etc., expecting it would populate a value in empty cells and I would then create a new column or scalar with the difference in values. I'm totally new to coding and querying. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Please update with desired input and output, preferably in table format. (In the edit pane, click the question mark on the top right, then click the 'Tables' tab to get guidance on how to create a table)

Comment: I have no clue what you're trying to do achieve here. Please provide an elaborated example which involves more than 2 cells.

Answer (score 0):

**KQL script:**

```
let X = datatable( c1:string , c2:int , c3:int )
[ 'a1',2,3,
'a2', 0,3,
'b1', 0,4
];
X
| project c1, c2, c3
| serialize
| extend prevC2 = prev(c2,1)
| extend c4 = c3 - prevC2
```

- Use **Serialize** operator to the table and then use **prev** function to get the previous row value.
- Then subtract the c3 value from previous row c2 value.

**Updated Script**

As per David דודו Markovitz's comment, I updated script.

```
let X = datatable( c1:string , c2:int , c3:int )
[ 'a1',2,3,
'a2', 0,3,
'b1', 0,4
];
X| serialize c4 = c3 - prev(c2)
```

**Output data**

| c1 | c2 | c3 | prevc2 | c4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | 2 | 3 |  |  |
| a2 | 0 | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| b1 | 0 | 4 | 0 | 4 |

[image]

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: This can all be written as one line: `X | serialize c4 = c3 - prev(c2)`. Having said that - it is meaningless. Nothing defines the order or the rows in this data set or the relation between them.

Comment: *Serialize* is an operator, not a function